# RegularExpressionValidator always fails, but ValidationExpression works in testing

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I found the answer to this, but it's a bit of a gotcha so I wanted to share it here.

I have a regular expression that validates passwords. They should be 7 to 60 characters with at least one numeric and one alpha character. Pretty standard. I used positive lookaheads (the **(?=** operator) to implement it:

```
(?=^.{7,60}$)(?=.*[0-9].*)(?=.*[a-zA-Z].*)
```

I checked this expression in my unit tests using **Regex.IsMatch()**, and it worked fine. However, when I use it in a RegularExpressionValidator, it always fails. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's strange that I've never run into this before, but it turns out that the RegularExpressionValidator doesn't use Regex.IsMatch or JavaScript's **Regex.test()** -- it checks for a capturing match that exactly equals the full tested value. Here's the relevant JS code:

```
var rx = new RegExp(val.validationexpression);
var matches = rx.exec(value);
return (matches != null && value == matches[0]);
```

So if the expression is all lookaheads (which match positions, not the actual text), it will fail. This is clearer with the example of an expression that only partially matches, e.g. with **\d{5}**, the value "123456" would fail. It's not just that it adds "^$" around your expression and does an IsMatch. Your expression actually has to capture.

The fix in my case is this expression:

```
(?=^.{7,60}$)(?=.*[0-9].*).*[a-zA-Z].*
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
(?=^.{7,60}$)(?=.*[0-9].*)(?=.*[a-zA-Z].*).+
//                                        ^^
```

? The regex should need something to consume.

Comment: Right that's the problem. Just wanted to write up what I found as an answer. Thanks!